# jQuery - How do I fadein a partially transparent div and retain the opacity?

Tags: jquery

My div is Opacity:0.7 and filter:alpha(opacity=70);

Fading out works fine

Fading in, it fades all the way to 1 and so is no longer transparent.

How can I fade it in to 0.7?

I tried a .fadeIn followed by .animate but .animate errors as the div is still display:none at that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use [`fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/):

```
// When you want to fade in:
$("div").fadeTo( "slow", 0.7 );

// When you want to fade out:
$("div").fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help.

http://hv-designs.co.uk/2010/01/13/learn-how-to-add-a-jquery-fade-in-and-out-effect/

What can i do with this code your about to give me? Basically its a fade in fade out effect. The effect fades an element to 50% on arrival of the website, then when you hover over it, it fades to 100%. The effect can be assigned to basically anything in a website wether it be an image, text, a link or even a div.